# Comparing RK4 to Euler method

Tags: julia, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I took a course in computational physics and I was given in an assigment to solve the equation of simple harmonic oscillator x_dot_dot = -x . I wrtoe the script in Julia for both methods

```
function RK4(x0 , F, T , dt) 

F1(f) = x -> f(x...)
F2(f) = x -> f((x .+ 0.5*dt*F1(f)(x))...)
F3(f) = x -> f((x .+ 0.5*dt*F2(f)(x))...)
F4(f) = x -> f((x .+ dt*F3(f)(x))...)

t = 0:dt:T
x = zeros(length(t), length(x0))
x[1,:] = x0
for n in 1:length(t) - 1
    act(F)  = map(f -> f(x[n,:]) , F)'
    x[n+1,:]= x[n,:] .+ (dt/6)*(act(F1.(F)) .+ 2*act(F2.(F)) + 2*act(F3.(F)) + act(F4.(F)))
end
return (x,t)
end

function euler(x0 , F, T , dt) 

F1(f) = x -> f(x...)

t = 0:dt:T
x = zeros(length(t), length(x0))
x[1,:] = x0
for n in 1:length(t)-1
    act(F)  = map(f -> f(x[n,:]) , F)'
    x[n+1,:]= x[n,:] .+ dt.* act(F1.(F))
end
return (x,t)
end
```

the code works and it solves the ODE for both methods  by when i plot the solutions it seems that the RK4 isn't compensating the Euler method when trying them both with equal time steps. When i try to use with RK4 with say half time step than Euler, Euler always shows more accurte results and when i try to use a timestep of say `dt = 0.01` for both methods the plots look almost identically the same.

The rest of the code :

```
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings
include("./methods.jl")


x0 = [1,0]
f1(x,v)= v
f2(x,v) = -x

plt = plot(xlabel = L"t")

xe , t = euler(x0 , [f1 f2] , 10*2π , 0.0005)
plot!(t, xe[:,1] , label = "Euler")
xr , t = RK4(x0 , [f1 f2] , 10*2π , 0.0005)
plot!(t, xr[:,1] , label = "RK4")

# Analytical solution
#plot!(t, cos.(t))

display(plt)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can not separate the vector implementation of any higher order RK method by the component functions. You always compute every stage of the method for all component functions and state components at once. The functional approach might look sophisticated, but directly computing the vectors as results of vector-valued functions with vector arguments is more robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `RK4` is less accurate is because of a bug. The implementation in the question is really obfuscated. And even non-indented. There is definitely better and more efficient ways to implement this and there are certainly packages in Julia which do so.

A fixed `RK4` can be:

```
function RK4(x0 , F, T , dt) 
    F1(f) = x -> f(x...)
    F2(f) = x -> f((x .+ 0.5*dt*[F1(g)(x) for g in F]')...)
    F3(f) = x -> f((x .+ 0.5*dt*[F2(g)(x) for g in F]')...)
    F4(f) = x -> f((x .+ dt*[F3(g)(x) for g in F]')...)

    t = 0:dt:T
    x = zeros(length(t), length(x0))
    x[1,:] = x0
    for n in 1:length(t) - 1
        act(F)  = map(f -> f(x[n,:]) , F)'
        x[n+1,:]= x[n,:] .+ (dt/6)*(act(F1.(F)) .+ 2*act(F2.(F)) + 2*act(F3.(F)) + act(F4.(F)))
    end
    return (x,t)
end
```

Note the definitions of `F2`, `F3`, `F4` have changed.
The original definition worked because the following broadcasting

```
julia> [1.2 1.2] .+ 0.5
1×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.7  1.7
```

worked on the `F1(f)(x)` output erroneously.